# How inlining could constrain binary compatibility for upgrade releases

Tags: c++, inline

I know that excessive use of inline functions could affect binary upgradeability. This is must be avoided when upgradeability is important. But, I can't figure out how inlining could affect binary compatibility. Please, could someone illustrate that.

Comment: That is way too vague. Try some google searches and or a different stack to ask question. This one is really for coding.

Comment: I think proper use of inline functions has something to do with coding also :)

Comment: True. I may have been wrong.

Comment: This is probably a programmers.SE question, but the answer given is quite good and I don't want to mess with it.

Answer (score 3):

When declaring your functions, variables, and types (aka, your "symbols"), you should also declare them as exported. Different compilers achieve this in different ways ([Visual Studio uses `__declspec(dllexport)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx) (and some other methods which I'm too lazy to google for you) while [GCC uses various Visibility switches](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility). I believe clang uses GCC semantics (or is relatively compatible) and am unfamiliar with other compilers' methods for exporting symbols.

If you inline your function *and it actually gets inlined* (which, if you declared it as an exportable symbol, I would argue that to be a compiler bug) then how do you call it from outside of your library? As part of the inlining process for functions the compiler will often remove or rework prologue and epilogue instructions since they're no longer needed (for example, no more need to `retn` on x86 -- just store the return value in the register it's going to be used).

Now suppose that on one early version of your library you had used some function which was declared inline but did not actually get inline (for example, a recursive function). Someone else comes along and starts using your library. In a later version, you rework your code to remove the recursion; suddenly the compiler *can* inline the function and opts to, therefore hiding the export. Now your existing customers (whoever's using your library) have missing symbols. You've broken binary compatibility.

Comment: @inetnght: Good example, thanks. So, when there is a massive use of inline functions  the chance that upgradeability is affected increases. To me it sounds a bit dangerous that we don't have total control over it. I can do my best to write inline functions in a proper way (avoid while loops, recursion, etc) to give them higher chance to get effectively inlined by the compiler, but this is not guaranteed. Do you agree with me?

Comment: No, I would not say it's dangerous: if you exercise proper declaration of export control (telling the compiler that you want to export something) and proper unit/integration/export testing (for example, creating another project specifically to test the importability of your exports which gets automatically triggered on every build) you can mitigate and manage issues caused by binary incompatibility by detecting these problems before shipping new versions (assuming you have all of this in place and properly use all of the features).

Comment: Does that means that someone's function that was not declared inline but got inlined anyway (by the compiler's decision) can also break binary compatibility, in the same way as in @inetknght 's example?

Comment: Suppose you have library A which links against library B. B exported symbol `foobar` in 1.0 but was inlined in 2.0. Now, library A was built and linked against an _unspecified_ B. If A used B 1.0's headers, then A should be compatible with B 1.0 (with regards to `foobar`) but will error if B 2.0 is installed (because `foobar` is no longer exported). If A used B 2.0's headers, then A should be compatible with B 1.0 and 2.0 (unless there are other additional problems); but then beware: if B 1.0 is installed, then B's exported `foobar` functionality will not be used by A (because A has 2.0!).